# TemporalPoint as an array

Tags: encog

Looks like my original question was not well formed so I will make it a little simpler :

Why is TemporalPoint an array ? 
In the book I see a TemporalPoint object called point .
Brief code sample shows point.Data[0] and point.Data[1] . What would Data[1] represent ? 
The actual full code example shows only Data[0] being used so there is no example in 
the book that actually uses Data[1] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many examples of forecasting use a single value to predict future trends.  For example, you might use data[0] to represent the value company1, to predict company1. However, you can use multiple values to predict company1.  Perhaps you might want to put the volume of company1 into data[1].  You might also want to use the values of company1, company2 and company3 to predict company 1.  In this case you place company1, company2 and company3 all into data[0], data[1] and data[2] respectively.

If you were using the above length 3 array, then you have 3 TemporalDataDescription objects to describe each of these array elements.  There is some more information in the Javadoc for TemporalMLDataSet and TemporalDataDescription. Links at: http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog

Comment: OK thanks ...that's kind of what I thought . And how does TemporalDataDescription fit with that ? When you add a description , that is describing data[0] correct ? Is the second description you add describing data[1] ? Is it just a matter of what sequence you add the descriptions ?

Comment: You need a description for each data[..] element.  See the edit above.

Comment: But how do you know which description goes with which data[i] element ? I don't see this explained in the docs but I guess the descriptions are indexed the same way as the point data elements then ?

Comment: Yes the indexes line up.